# charset encoding Tomcat Windows / JBoss Linux

Tags: json, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding, jboss

I have 2 servers: 1 Tomcat 6 in windows and one JBoss 5 in linux.

When writing JSON (applicatio/json) to ouputstream I get special characters (Á,á, etc..) right in Tomcat but wrong in JBoss.

This is how I right to the output stream:

```
protected void writeToOutputStream(String response, String tag) {
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        logInfo("Writing to output stream");
        outputStream = httpresponse.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(response.getBytes(), 0, response.getBytes().length);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logError("Could not write response into output stream", ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

If I force the charset with

```
httpresponse.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

It gets ok in JBoss but not in tomcat...

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response.getBytes() uses the platform default encoding to convert String to bytes and the encodings are very likely not the same on your Windows (CP-1252) and Linux machine (utf-8).

You should pass to getBytes() the encoding (preferably 'utf-8' ) which must be identical to the one specified as the `charset`in your `content-type` response header (utf-8 in your code above).

As a side note, the way you write to the Outpustream and the double call to getBytes() is quite inefficient. If you want to keep your code small yet efficient, use Apache commons-io and utilities like IOUtils.copy() to manipulate streams.

Comment: Solved! I noticed that double call to getBytes. Now I'm doing it just once, thanks for the tip !